# Do any characters from Jumanji appear in Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle?

Tags: jumanji, jumanji-welcome-to-the-jungle

I'm thinking about going to see *Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle* and I was wondering, do any of the characters from the original *Jumanji* appear in it?
I'm interested in both the actual characters, played by the same or different actors, and the actors from the original film appearing in a cameo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one (altered) character that appears in both movies: **Van Pelt**.

In *Jumanji*, he's a big game hunter that escapes from the game into the real world. In *Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle*, he's been transformed by the game into an explorer and antagonist/rival to the PCs. The two are also played by different actors: Jonathan Hyde vs Bobby Cannavale.

Comment: Do we know if it is the same Van Pelt? Couldn't it be his son or even grandson?

Comment: @Skooba I mean, Van Pelt isn't real--the game transformed itself to fit a 90s video game aesthetic; it makes sense to me that it'd transform its main antagonist as well. Narrative continuity isn't something it needs. But if it helps: Alex had been there for 20 years. He entered right after the first Jumanji movie. and felt like a matter of weeks or months had passed. Cannavale was about 45 at the time of filming Jumanji 2; Hyde about 45 when filming Jumanji 1. Not old enough to be the dad, assuming Van Pelt 2.0 has been there the whole time, which as the main antagonist makes sense.

Comment: The Jumanji WIki points out that Van Pelt in Welcome to the Jungle is closer to the Van Pelt from the Animated Series, maybe he was based off of that?

Comment: Nora Shepherd, Judy and Peter's aunt from the first movie, appears in Jumanji: The Next Level. She is the same character, and portrayed by the same actress (Bebe Neuwirth), albeit likely from the 'new' timeline established the end of the first film.

Answer (score 5):

### No.

I saw the new one recently and as far as I remember there are no cameos by any original movie actor. However, there are subtle references to characters from the previous movie.

The references which I noticed are (Spoiler Alert!):

> You can see the original Jumanji Board in the beginning of the movie.
>   There is also a reference to Alan Parrish (Robin William's Character from the original movie) when the actors are inside Jumanji.